# MFC: TAB order programmatically for controls

Tags: c++, mfc, tab-ordering

I am using the default CButton and created 3 buttons programmatically..

```
BOOL CTestDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
    CRect rect;


    GetClientRect(&rect);

    CRect btnRect = CRect(rect.left+50,100,rect.left+150,150);
    button1.Create(_T("ONE"),BS_FLAT | WS_VISIBLE,btnRect,this,1); 

    btnRect.MoveToX(200);
    button2.Create(_T("TWO"),BS_FLAT | WS_VISIBLE,btnRect,this,2); 


    btnRect.MoveToX(350);
    button3.Create(_T("THREE"),BS_FLAT | WS_VISIBLE,btnRect,this,3); 



    return TRUE;  
}
```

If i see the O/P, always the Buton ONE is highlighted and no TAB is working.

How to support TAB order and how to change the focus. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created the buttons without the necessary **windows** styles.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw4e0cww.aspx):

> Apply the following window styles to a button control:

- WS_CHILD  Always
- WS_VISIBLE   Usually
- WS_DISABLED   Rarely
- WS_GROUP   To group controls
- WS_TABSTOP   To include the button in the tabbing order